# get file size of a file to wget before wget-ing it?

Tags: command-line, wget

I'm wondering if there is a way to check ahead of time the size of a file I might download via `wget`? I know that using the `--spider` option tells me if a file exists or not, but I'm interested in finding the size of that file as well.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Hmm.. for me `--spider` does display the size:

```
$ wget --spider http://henning.makholm.net/
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2011-08-08 19:39:48--  http://henning.makholm.net/
Resolving henning.makholm.net (henning.makholm.net)... 85.81.19.235
Connecting to henning.makholm.net (henning.makholm.net)|85.81.19.235|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 9535 (9.3K) [text/html]     <-------------------------
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.

$
```

(But beware that not all web servers will inform clients of the length of the data except by closing the connection when it's all been sent.)

If you're concerned about wget changing the format it reports the length in, you might use `wget --spider --server-response` and look for a `Content-Length` header in the output.

Comment: Just for completeness, here's extraction of the size only: `wget http://example.com --spider --server-response -O - 2>&1 | sed -ne '/Content-Length/{s/.*: //;p}'`

Comment: For FTP, look for this in the output: `--> SIZE filename.ext

213 ########`

Comment: What is length returns unspecified: `Length: unspecified [application/zip]` @Henning Makholm

Comment: @alper: In that case the server at the other end _will not tell you_ how long the file will be unless you download all of it.

Comment: What about aria2?

Comment: solution that works without -S (--server-response)  and just parses Lenght: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16499/162125

Comment: BTW the command `wget --method=HEAD` works the same as `--spider`

Answer (score 39):

```
curl --head URL
```

Look for "Content-Length:" in the output.

And thanks to Henning Makholm's comment:

```
wget --spider URL
```

and look for "Length:" in the output.

Comment: Although doing it with `wget` would be more pleasing (-:

Comment: `wget -S` (`wget --server-response`) shows the same header information, but then it goes on to download the file, so that's not useful for the question.  I don't see an option for wget to show the headers without fetching the file.  For example, ``tries=0` means infinite retries.

Comment: For some reason the `wget` option to do only HEAD is spelled `--spider`.

Comment: There's a workaround that allows `wget -S` to work; see my answer.

Comment: What if `Content-Length` does not exist?

Comment: @alper Then the server isn't telling you the size.

Comment: @KeithThompson :-( Is there any workaround/hack to capture the size from the server?

Comment: @alper Probably not. If the server wanted to give you the size, it would use `Content-Length` to do so. Consider that the thing you're looking at might not be a file with a defined size; it might be the the of some program. In that case, the only way to know the size is to download the data and count the bytes.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a way to predict the size before of the file before download aiming  if the size of the data is large I halt the download process. Maybe I can check the downloaded size while `wget` actively downloads it, where  add a download limit to wget, hence if exceeds the limit stop the download process.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking for the size of a directory and google got me here. While there is no direct answer here, the accepted answer helped me to build the following command on top of it:

```
wget --spider -m -np URL-to-dir 2>&1 | sed -n -e /unspecified/d -e '/^Length: /{s///;s/ .*//;p}' | paste -s -d+ | bc
```

The above runs `wget` in a spider mode for the entire directory, which ends up logging the length for each file in that directory. The output is then piped to `sed` to extract a sequence of numbers (byte sizes). The last two components in the pipe simply help sum it up to get the total in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
size_bytes=$(wget -S "${url}" --start-pos=500G 2>&1 | grep Content-Length | cut -d: -f2)
```